# Remove results with field==0 from serializer response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use ModelSerializer to return serialized data of a model:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_category_count')

    def _category_count(self, obj):
        category_obj = Category.objects.get(id=obj.id)
        questions_count = Question.objects.filter(category=category_obj).count()
        return questions_count

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ["id", "category", "category_count"]
```

What I get write now is here:

```
 [{
        "category": "orzecznictwo lekarskie",
        "category_count": 0,
        "id": 9
    },
    {
        "category": "zdrowie publiczne",
        "category_count": 1,
        "id": 10
    }
]
```

I want to remove objects with category_count == 0 from serialization

```
[
        {
            "category": "zdrowie publiczne",
            "category_count": 1,
            "id": 10
        }
    ]
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    (...)



 class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.TextField()
    category_slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: show us LepAppPytanie and LepAppDzial models

Comment: Please translate the field and model names to English, it's very hard to read for someone who doesn't know Romanian.

Comment: @Melv I've translated the fields into English

Comment: @iklinac I've added LepAppPytanie (Question) and LepAppDzial (Category) models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating the field inside the serializer and then want to discard the object. That's not how things work: serializers merely change representation of data. Which data is displayed is determined in views.

```py
class CategoryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Category.objects.annotate(
            question_count=Count("question_set")
        ).exclude(question_count=0)
```

And in the serializer, you don't have to create the count any more and add the 'question_count' to `Meta.fields`.

[Recommended reading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

*Edit*:

Forgot that DRF will check the field on the model and fail, so you need to declare the field:

```py
class CategoryWithQuestionCount(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Category
        fields = ("pk", "category", "question_count")
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about removing it in the ModelSerializer. But you can try overriding get_queryset() or changing the queryset in your View:

```
queryset = Class.objects.exclude(dzial_liczba_pytan=0)
```

Comment: That won't work, cause it's a generated serializer field, not a model field.

Comment: @Melvyn The data he get will be from a ViewSet no? then isn't it easier just to exclude the data in the ViewSet?

Comment: You can only include records in the view, not in serializer, but again - dzial_liczba_pytan is not a model field, so you can't filter on it.

Comment: oh yeah that's true, my mistake.